# Animation modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

Hi I'm new to blender current version 2.78 , and I'm currently trying to complete this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JDtLqxijTE ) ver 2.77 )
when I get to around 12 minutes or the copying modifiers part , nothing happens , there is a post on the tutorial saying this part doesnt work in 2,78 version or its a bug , can anyone help with this please , ? in way of a work a round ? thanks for the time ...

Comment: You can just select those bones one by one and add *Cycles* FCurve modifier for each bone manually (as there are only 4 of them) if copying modifier really doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but I still can not add the foot bone modifiers ,so they  get past frame 25 , even adding them independently , checked all parenting , I have no issues there ( comments changed in last few hours ) on the YT page , any other advice would be appreciated